# Is there a special code for a half symbol?

Tags: mysql

Because my database is about postage stamps there are a lot of half symbols in the descriptions. They type into mysql with no problem but when I get the results of a query all the half symbols have been replaced by a question mark.
Is there a special code I should be using when I input the descriptions instead of using the half symbol? Otherwise, is there another solution like changing the character set. I'm using utf-8 at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are facing character encoding issue. You should use UTF-8 everywhere:

- Make sure the column that contains text data is encoded as `utf8_...`
- Check that when you get information from database, you keep this encoding. You can force it by sending `SET NAMES utf8;` before any request to MySQL.
- Check that when you display this information the encoding is UTF-8 (in a webpage, that means `<meta charset='utf-8'>` in `<head>`).